# How to find the neighborhood for certain vertices only?

Tags: r, igraph

The question was started [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3242483/how-to-define-condition-for-spliting-vertices-on-corner-and-non-corner-vertices).

I have an undirected graph `g` with `n<100` vertices. The graph is simple. The coordinates of all vertices are integer `(x_i, y_i), i=1, 2,..., n`, the set of edges is predefinded, they are line segments with the length `1` unit. 
The degree of vertices can be `2`, `3` or `4`.

```
library(igraph)

g <- graph_from_literal(1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-1, 8-9-4)
B <- t(matrix(c(0,0, 0,1, 0,2, -1,2, -2,2, -2,1, -2,0, -1,0, -1,1), nrow =2));

V(g)$id <- seq_len(vcount(g))

V(g)$x <- B[,1]; V(g)$y <- B[,2]

plot(g, layout=as.matrix(B))
```

[image]

I need to set the new attribute for vertex the `corner` attribute.

We say the vertex `i` is the `corner` vertex if its degree is `2` and two incident edges do not lie on the same line. On the plot above vertices `1, 3, 5, 7` are corner vertices while remaining vertices `2, 4, 6, 8, 9` are non-corner.

**My attempt**

I have found the list of vertices that have degree equal to `2`.

```
idv <- V(g)[strength(g)==2]; idv # 1 2 3 5 6 7 9
```

Then the list of neighborhood vertices for `i`-th vertex was found.

```
neigh<-neighborhood(g, idv); neigh
```

The error is here, because I see the neighborhood vertices for all vertices, no only vertices that have degree equal to `2`. For instance,

```
neigh[[4]]; neigh[[8]];   
#[1] 4 3 5 9
#[1] 8 1 7 9
```

**Question.** How to use the `neighborhood` function to find the neighborhood for vertices with degree `2` only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is correct, but the second argument isn't about vertices of interest, it's the third one:

```
neighborhood
# function (graph, order = 1, nodes = V(graph), mode = c("all", 
#     "out", "in"), mindist = 0) 
# {
# ...
```

Thus,

```
length(neighborhood(g, nodes = idv))
# [1] 7
```

does the job.