# How to work with the lists that have different lengths?

Tags: r, list, for-loop, igraph, lapply

The question was started [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56392883/how-to-find-the-neighborhood-for-certain-vertices-only).

I have an undirected graph `g` with `n<100` vertices. The graph is simple. The coordinates of all vertices are integer `(x_i, y_i), i=1, 2,..., n`, the set of edges is predefinded, they are line segments with the length `1` unit. 
The degree of vertices can be `2`, `3` or `4`.

```
library(igraph)

g <- graph_from_literal(1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-1, 8-9-4)
B <- t(matrix(c(0,0, 0,1, 0,2, -1,2, -2,2, -2,1, -2,0, -1,0, -1,1), nrow =2));

V(g)$id <- seq_len(vcount(g))

V(g)$x <- B[,1]; V(g)$y <- B[,2]

plot(g, layout=as.matrix(B))
```

[image]

I need to set the new attribute for vertex the `corner` attribute.

We say the vertex `i` is the `corner` vertex if its degree is `2` and two incident edges do not lie on the same line. On the plot above vertices `1, 3, 5, 7` are corner vertices while remaining vertices `2, 4, 6, 8, 9` are non-corner.

I have found the list of vertices that have degree equal to `2`.

```
idv <- V(g)[strength(g)==2]; idv # 1 2 3 5 6 7 9
```

Then the list of neighborhood vertices for `i`-th vertex was found and new attribur was created:

```
neigh<-neighborhood(g, nodes=idv); neigh
V(g)$corner <- 0
```

**My attempt**

```
for(i in idv){
    ifelse(V(g)[neigh[[i]][2]]$x == V(g)[neigh[[i]][3]]$x || 
           V(g)[neigh[[i]][2]]$y == V(g)[neigh[[i]][3]]$y, 
    V(g)[neigh[[i]][1]]$corner <- 0, 
    V(g)[neigh[[i]][1]]$corner <- 1)}
```

But I have the error `Error in neigh[[i]] : subscript out of bounds`

In common case the length of `neigh` is less or equvalent of the length `V(g)$id`:

```
length(neigh)     # 7
length(V(g)$id)   # 9
```

And I cann't compare the coorditates `(x_i, y_i)`.

**Question.** How to work with the lists that have different lengths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case, one solution would be to relate `i` from `idv` with an element of `neigh`. For instance, `neigh[[i]][2]` could be rewritten as `neigh[i == idv][[1]][2]]` and in total we have

```
for(i in idv){
  ifelse(V(g)[neigh[i == idv][[1]][2]]$x == V(g)[neigh[i == idv][[1]][3]]$x || 
           V(g)[neigh[[i]][2]]$y == V(g)[neigh[i == idv][[1]][3]]$y, 
         V(g)[neigh[i == idv][[1]][1]]$corner <- 0, 
         V(g)[neigh[i == idv][[1]][1]]$corner <- 1)}
```

---

However, that is quite convoluted and hard to read. Instead we may exploit the fact that each of `idv` have the same number of neighbours and `neigh` can be transformed into a matrix:

```
neigh <- do.call(rbind, neigh)
```

Then we simply have

```
V(g)$corner[neigh[, 1]] <- V(g)[neigh[, 2]]$x != V(g)[neigh[, 3]]$x &
  V(g)[neigh[, 2]]$y != V(g)[neigh[, 3]]$y
```